# how to extract value from a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Scipy.Optimize.fmin to find the maximum of a function. The output is in the form of a numpy.ndarray with additional information on the process. I need just the x value returned as a float.

```
def f(x):
    """returns the value of f(x) with the input value x"""
    import math
    f = math.exp(-x ** 2.0) / (1.0 + x ** 2.0) + \
        2.0 * (math.cos(x) ** 2.0) / (1.0 + (x - 4.0) ** 2.0)
    return f

def find_max_f():
    """returns the x for which f(x) takes the maximum value"""
    import scipy.optimize as o
    m = o.fmin(lambda x: -f(x), 0)
    return m
```

This is what it returns:

```
>>> find_max_f()
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: -1.118012
     Iterations: 12
     Function evaluations: 24
array([ 0.0131875])
```

I just need the final number inside the brackets labeled array

Comment: What is the return type of `fmin()`? If it's an iterable you might be able to grab it using the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply bind the result to something and then you can index the first element as if it were a list or tuple:

```
>>> xopt = find_max_f()
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -1.118012
         Iterations: 12
         Function evaluations: 24
>>> xopt
array([ 0.0131875])
>>> xopt[0]
0.013187500000000005
>>> type(xopt[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

I recommend reading the [NumPy Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial), in particular the section on "Indexing, Slicing and Iterating".

Comment: You might also want to mention unpacking. E.g. `xopt, = find_max_f()` (or `m, = o.fmin(...)` inside `find_max_f`.)  It winds up confusing a lot of newcomers, but it's a common idiom, so it might be good for the OP to see it as well.

Comment: I think you just did. :^)  Can't quite explain why I don't use that pattern, but I never use it in my own code.